# Ruby On Rails Returning Array NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ibm-midrange, db2-400

We've been continuously working on this issue for a few months and not getting far with it. Since this was first asked, we changed the code (based on what the original developer for the site suggested), but we are still not getting where we need to be.

I'm relatively new to Ruby and am currently taking some courses to learn more about it, so please bear with me. We're using Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2 We use AS 400/DB2 for our database.

We have an online ordering site that you have to have an account set up to access. Depending on what type of account you are set up as, you might have to have your order approved by someone. I.e. if I am a drop ship account, my distributor has to approve what I'm ordering. Also if I am a dedicated drop ship account, my distributor has to approve what I'm ordering as well.

UPDATED 07/07/14

---

initially, For accounts with 1-2 email addresses everything works great, however in instances where there are more that two  we get a NoMethodError:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `prfdstw1' for nil:NilClass): 
app/models/order.rb:355:in `submit_order'
```

We have now been testing with different accounts for several hours and now there does not appear to be a definite pattern to the accounts the fail vs succeed, about 50% of the tests are working regardless of number of emails or type of account.

the lines in question are:

```
            if sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DS" or sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DSD"        
                rec = SignOn.first(:conditions => {:userw1 => login}, :select=> "prfdstw1") 
                webid = rec.prfdstw1 if rec
                def ignore_exception
                   begin
                     yield  
                   rescue Exception
                  end
                end
```

and

```
target_email = Contact.connection.select_values
("SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = #
{Contact.connection.quote(rec.prfdstw1)}").uniq
```

and

```
if sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DS" or sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DSD" 
                # If there is no distributor email address, the mailer model will
 substitute in the admin's email from their settings
                 target_email.each do | email_address | 
Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(email_address, 'Coastal Pet Online 
Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>', "Order Confirmation Approval", email_details)
                 end
```

Is there a better way to return the array that would allow for more than 2 emails? I am now unsure of the `target_email` line. we are getting some accounts with no email addresses that are still working, thee doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason to this at all.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you 100% sure it is the case with more than two emails? Looks more like an issue with no (zero) email addresses?

Comment: yes the one that fail have always had more than 2 emails. I did run into a case where there were no emails and yes that one failed too, but I am testing null higher on the page shouldn't that account for the zero? I will update the question with the other section of code.

Comment: It's simple, either `rec` is empty, or 'rec' doesn't respond to `prfdstw1` because it doesn't know the method, so add a breakpoint before that line, or use `logger.debug rec` to see its value in server logs.

Comment: @UriAgassi rec = SignOn.first(:conditions => {:userw1 => login}, :select=> "prfdstw1")  this works in other cases it seems to only fail when there are 3 or more email values rec should never be empty since that is the user login that was used to get to this point in the code.